# Pandas: np.vectorize slow to update values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to iterate through a dataframe of snooker matches one match at a time so that, following each match, I can update the ratings of the players involved.

I have written some code which achieves this but it is rather slow (approx. 10 minute run-time for 36000 matches/rows). I have a feeling it is to do with my use of np.vectorize, which I used because I know of no other way to get a function working on a pandas df to take multiple arguments (my get_match_rating function - see below - takes three arguments).

matches_fil3 is the name of the dataframe. All the functions I am using are very simple (just one or two lines of very basic maths). So that's why I'm thinking this is an np.vectorize issue - is there a faster/more Pythonic way of achieving this?

```
for i in range(0, len(matches_fil3)):
    matches_fil3.loc[i, 'P1Est'] = np.vectorize(get_estimate)(matches_fil3['Player One'].iloc[i], i)
    matches_fil3.loc[i, 'P1Err'] = np.vectorize(get_error)(matches_fil3['Player One'].iloc[i], i)
    matches_fil3.loc[i, 'P2Est'] = np.vectorize(get_estimate)(matches_fil3['Player Two'].iloc[i], i)
    matches_fil3.loc[i, 'P2Err'] = np.vectorize(get_error)(matches_fil3['Player Two'].iloc[i], i)
    matches_fil3.loc[i, 'P1Rat'] = np.vectorize(get_match_rating)(matches_fil3['P1 Frames Won'].iloc[i], matches_fil3['Total'].iloc[i], matches_fil3['P1Exp'].iloc[i])
    matches_fil3.loc[i, 'P2Rat'] = np.vectorize(get_match_rating)(matches_fil3['P2 Frames Won'].iloc[i], matches_fil3['Total'].iloc[i], matches_fil3['P2Exp'].iloc[i])
```

Comment: To use additional arguments on `df.apply()` use the `args` parameter inside `apply` to enter arguments for the second position onwards

Comment: The point of `np.vectorize` is not to avoid doing a loop for each row? does it work if you do `matches_fil3['P1Est'] = np.vectorize(get_estimate)(matches_fil3['Player One'], range(0, len(matches_fil3)))` outside of the loop for?

Comment: np.vectorize runs a for loop internally. From the docs: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: `np.vectorize` is **not** vectorised in the "contiguous memory block calculation" sense. In my opinion, it's poorly named. More accurate, `np.loopy`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better and faster way to make this work is using apply function. They are internally optimized for fast performance.

You can rewrite your code like:

```
matches_fil3['P1Est'] = matches_fil3['Player One'].apply(get_estimate)
matches_fil3['P1Err'] = matches_fil3['Player One'].apply(get_error)
.
.
matches_fil3['P2Rat'] = matches_fil3.apply(lambda row: get_match_rating(row['P2 Frames Won'], row['Total'], row['P2Exp']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you write this so that each row is dealt with in turn (i.e. first row zero, then row one, etc)? That was the purpose of the...for i in range(0, len(matches_fil3)):
    matches_fil3.loc[i, 'P1Est'] = ....

Comment: @TomDry yes, the apply function works row wise only. I think you should check the results, they should be same. or if you can provide a sample data, few rows and expected output I can check.

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have been more clear. I want to run ALL the functions on row zero, then ALL the functions on row one, etc. Basically row one has to be done (i.e. seen to by all the functions) before I go onto row two. What you're doing is running one function on every row, then the next function on every row, and so on.

Comment: @TomDry okay i understood, but aren't both things the same since we are not modifying original columns and creating new ones ?